# Why do I get "none" when I run the code? Without using def

Tags: python-3.x

For some reason I get "none" when I ask for input from the user, it doesn't matter if it's in a function.

```
age = input(print("whats your age: "))
print(f"Your age is {age}")
```

output:
whats your age: 
None50
Your age is 50

Comment: `age = input("whats your age: ")` use this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`input` already prints its param.
`print` returns `None`. that's why input prints `None`.

try this:

```py
age = input("whats your age: ")
print(f"Your age is {age}")
```

Comment: Why duplicates are answered?